# Como fazer tabela estrangeira associar campos usando select?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Em meu projeto eu tenho uma função na qual busca todos os elementos do banco de dados e ainda faz com que `"categoria_id"` se torne `"categoria_nome"` requisitando o campo em outra tabela, porém quando tento usar este `select` novamente recebo este erro:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\warehouse\assets\php\bancos\banco-produtos.php on line 16

Segue abaixo as funções:

**listaProdutos:**

```
function listaProdutos($conexao) {
    $produtos = array();
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select p.*, c.nome as categoria_nome 
    from produtos as p join categorias as c on p.categoria_id = c.id");

    while($produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        array_push($produtos, $produto);
    }

    return $produtos;
}
```

**buscaProdutos**

```
function buscaProduto($conexao, $id) {
    $query = "select p.*, c.nome as categoria_nome from produtos as p where id ={$id} join categorias as c on p.categoria_id = c.id";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
 }
```

Como posso fazer para que ocorra a assimilação entre os campos ?

**Estrutura do banco de dados:**

```
 *Tabela Produtos:* 

 id

 nome

 descricao

 quantidade

 categoria_id

 localizacao

 ponto_minimo

 ponto_maximo


 *Tabela Categorias:*

  id

  nome
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que sua query está errada, o `where` tem que ser depois de seu join e você tem duas colunas com o nome "ID", então você tem que passar o alias.

Altere para:

```
select 
   p.*, 
   c.nome as categoria_nome 
from produtos as p
join categorias as c on p.categoria_id = c.id
where p.id = {$id}
```

Caso queira ver se está ocorrendo algum erro durante a execução da query, altere a linha:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
```

para:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
```

Comment: Eu estava utilizando o where depois do join, porém alterei a ordem para testar :D

Comment: Funcionou. vlw msm